# how let button go to bottom right corner?

Tags: swiftui

As the picture shows, I want the button to be in the bottom right corner.

[https://i.imgur.com/GiVor8a.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojhGL.png)

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Color.black
            }

            Button(action: {}) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.grid.1x2.fill")
                }
                .padding()
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .mask(Circle())
            }.frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            .border(Color.red, width: 1)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Spacer()` for that,

Here is Your Code :

```
ZStack {
            HStack {
                Color.black
            }

            VStack(alignment:.trailing) {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "rectangle.grid.1x2.fill")
                        }
                        .padding()
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .mask(Circle())
                    }.frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                }
            }
        }
```